# Show animated counting with RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular app, I want to show animated counting for records from HTTP get requests. I use RxJs but the response was returned very fast and I see only the final result from my request. I tried to increase clientsCount and show it in view. How I can to slow down a bit so that  can see how the number is gradually increasing as the request goes.

```
this.clients$ = this.clientService.getClients()
  .pipe(
    tap(e => console.log(e)),
    map(clients => {
      return clients
        .map((client) => { this.clientsCount++; return client })
        
    }),
    finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false; console.log('HJJHJG') }),
    catchError((err) => { this.isLoading = false; throw err }));
```

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delay

Comment: I know for the delay() but this makes all requests to wait, not for each record how I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, let me de-clutter your code a bit:

```ts
this.clients$ = this.clientService.getClients().pipe(
  tap(console.log),
  tap(clients => clients.forEach(client => this.clientsCount++)),
  finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false; console.log('HJJHJG') }),
  tap({error: err => this.isLoading = false})
);
```

You might notice something interesting, all the operators that you're using don't preform any transformations (the bread and butter of RxJS). They all just perform side effects.

Lets look at this line of code:

```ts
clients.forEach(client => this.clientsCount++)
```

This loop will run synchronously. This is semantically the same as:

```ts
this.clientsCount += clients.length
```

I'm not sure what you're hoping to slow down.

does `this.clientService.getClients()` emit more than one array of clients? You can spread that out with `zip` and `timer` like this:

```ts
const clientService$ = this.clientService.getClients().pipe(
  tap(console.log),
  tap(clients => this.clientsCount += clients.length),
  finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false; console.log('HJJHJG') }),
  tap({error: err => this.isLoading = false})
);

this.clients$ = zip(clientService$, timer(0,1000)).pipe(
  map([cs] => cs) // Remove timer info
);
```

If you want to turn your array of clients into a stream of clients you can do so like this:

```ts
this.clients$ = this.clientService.getClients().pipe(
  tap(console.log),
  concatMap(clients => zip(clients, timer(0,1000)),
  map([cs] => cs), // Remove timer info
  tap(() => this.clientsCount++),
  finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false; console.log('HJJHJG') }),
  tap({error: err => this.isLoading = false})
);
```